# "Rather" in modern English

Tags: grammar, difference, adverbs, predeterminers

I've stumbled upon a post in a Russian community, which teaches English, that says that "**rather**" isn't used (is avoided) in modern English, instead "**quite**" and "**really**" are used. However, I can't believe it since I know that there's a difference between "**rather**", "**quite**", and "**really**". Take for example this sentence:

- The room is **rather** small.

"**Rather**" means "*not too big*" here. If we place "**quite**" instead then it will mean "*not that big*" while if we place "**really**" then it will mean "*it's not big at all*". "**really**" sort of means "**very**"

So is it true that "**rather**" is avoided in Modern English?

Comment: How do they arrive at their conclusions? By visiting kindergartens and listening to what the toddlers say?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Btw, the same community claims that the word "**pupil**" is no longer in use in Modern English. I have no idea where they get this from!

Comment: **Student** has eaten **pupil**'s lunch, in modern AmE.

Comment: Also, just because a word isn't used doesn't mean it is being "avoided". **really** and **rather** are in different registers.

Comment: I'd *rather* they didn't simply toss perfectly good English words into the dust bin. It's *rather* rude, wouldn't you agree? (The word *rather* is in common use, don't worry.)

Comment: @Lawrence That's what really pisses me off too.

Comment: I was using that as a somewhat tongue-in-cheek example of how *rather* might be used in contemporary  speech.

Comment: @Lawrence I know. "**rather**" is a great word you can't leave without. Why dump it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking from a BrE perspective (there may well be differences with other dialects, but none I know of), *rather* isn't avoided in modern usage, but it is perhaps less common than other words that can be used synonymously, such as *quite*, *pretty*, fairly, *very* and *really*.

There are several words in English that can mean either *to a small/moderate extent* (fairly), or *to a great extent* (very), depending on the context. One such word is *quite*. For example:

> I guess he's *quite* tall. - *He's a bit tall, but not very tall.*
>
> (In surprise) You're quite tall! - *You're very tall!*

*Rather* is another example of such a word, but it tends to be used more towards the *to a great extent* meaning, although generally not quite to the extent of *very* or *really*. It can be seen as more formal then some of the other words (like pretty or really).

Answer (score 3):

***This Example***

In this example, "**rather**" can be likened to "**quite**". "**Very**" is too harsh.

The sentence

> The room is **rather** small

Means that the room is **quite** / **slightly** small, not very small.

***Other Example***

"Rather" may be used in place of "**very**" when someone is be being polite.

**e.g.**

> "How was your stay?"
>
> "It was ok, but the room was **rather** small"

The room may have been tiny, but "**rather**" would suffice to explain the problem.

***In Conclusion***

Ultimately, "**rather**" has multiple meanings depending on the situation, and can be used interchangeably in place of "**quite**" and "**very**".

I wouldn't say that "**rather**" is avoided in modern English. It may be considered slightly old-fashioned, but is still used.

Comment: I agree. If those Russians are correct, this native speaker never got the memo.